# Running Appium recorded test

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium

I am new to Appium. I started using the Appium app, added the simulator app file and lunched the simulator (using "launch"), as described [here](http://shashikantjagtap.net/ios-automated-testing-in-the-bdd-with-appium-cucumber-on-mac-osx/)

I also succeed recording a test on my app and got the Ruby output (is there an PHPUnit option?).

I cannot find any good knowledge base of how can I run/use this test now? (supposed I have already created / recorded a test)

Note: the only close thing I found is this:

```
bundle exec cucumber features/plain_note.feature
```

But it uses cucumber. How can I run a simple test just recorder in the inspector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to run your Appium Inspector saved ruby boilerplate tests.

1) Start the Appium server in terminal with this, and leave this terminal window open.

`$ appium &`

2) While the appium server is running in the previous terminal window, open a new terminal window and navigate to the directory where your tests are located and run them with this.

`$ ruby "your_test.rb"`

That should execute your Appium test you recorded with the Appium inspector.

If you have the Appium GUI running/open, you may have node issues about the same port already in use. If this happens simply run this in terminal.

```
$ killall node
```

If you don't already have the appium server installed you can install it by running this in terminal which requires npm to be installed.

```
$ npm install -g appium
```

Hope this helps.